# How to updated nested attribute value in factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, rspec-rails

we have one factory in which we are developing nested relation

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory : user do
    name "Arvind"
    association :campaign
    factory :user_with_photos do
      after(:build) do |user|
        user.photos.build name: 'user 1', 
        user.photos.build name: 'user 2',  position: 2
      end
    end
    factory :user_with_mandatory_photos do
      after(:build) do |user|
        user.photos.build name: 'user 3',  mandatory: true
        user.photos.build name: 'user 4',  mandatory: true
      end
    end

    factory :user_with_mandatory_photos do
      after(:build) do |user|
        user.photos.build name: 'user 5',  mandatory: false
        user.photos.build name: 'user 6',  mandatory: false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

we are creating attribute like

```
 users = FactoryGirl.create(:user_without_mandatory_fields, campaign: @campaign)

 users = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_mandatory_fields, campaign: @campaign)
```

we are looking to reduce this and use only

```
factory : user do
    name "Arvind"
    association :campaign
    factory :user_with_photos do
      after(:build) do |user|
        user.photos.build name: 'user 1', 
        user.photos.build name: 'user 2',  position: 2
      end
    end
end
```

But we are not getting how to create user photo with the mandatory field in this scenario. Can anyone please suggest?

```
Looking something like  users = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_photos,[update user photo attribute make mandatory true ] campaign: @campaign)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this problem with creating the new object of photos

```
photos = FactoryGirl.create_list(:photo, 12, mandatory: true)
users = FactoryGirl.create(:use, :photos, campaign: @campaign)
```